# TYPE = MYISAM throws SQL syntax error

Tags: mysql

For a website I am trying to build I need to manually import a sql file, but I get syntax errors and have no idea how to correct it.

```
    SQL query:

-- MySQL dump 8.21
--
-- Host: localhost Database: dnaowner_aqsg
-- Server version   3.23.49a
--
-- Table structure for table 'announce'
--
CREATE TABLE announce(
    id INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    stamp DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    txt TEXT NOT NULL ,
    postedby INT( 11 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
    PRIMARY KEY ( id )
) TYPE = MYISAM ;
```

MySQL said:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`type=myisam`' at line 16

Comment: Thanks for your question! I was working with old software and having the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

```
ENGINE = MyISAM ;
```

instead of

```
TYPE = MYISAM ;
```

`TYPE` was deprecated in `MySQL 4.0`

Comment: And removed in MySQL 5.5